# exec.Command Escaping Variables with JSON Payload

Tags: json, curl, go, escaping

Thank you in advance as I have spent 2 days on this. Here is a working curl command.

```
curl -ku login:pass -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'-d'{"type":"page","title":"Testpage","space":{"key":"ITDept"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>Blank Page.</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' https://confluence/rest/api/content
```

I need to get this to execute with exec.Command.

Given that now in Go I have tried escaping and all sorts of other means to get this to work.  The issue is more than likely this ridiculous JSON string that is required.  I have the JSON string saved into a var now to try it that way.

```
jsonPayload := '{"type":"page","title":"Testpage","space":{"key":"ITDept"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>Blank Page.</p>","representation":"storage"}}}'

execCmd := "bash", "-c", "curl -ku login:pass -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d" jsonPayload "https://confluence/rest/api/content"
```

So the jsonPayload is the argument to -d.  I have tried this using the Marshal json/encoding and the net/http package and it goes through but something about how that stdlib is sending it causes the API to state it is the wrong format.

I also have tried this with this and the curl copied out of the println works but when actually ran in golang it fails with incorrect format.

```
    env := os.Environ()
    curlCmd, err := exec.LookPath("curl")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Path not found to binary!")
        panic(err)
    }
args := []string{"curl", "-ku", "login:pass", "-X", "POST", "-H", "'Content-Type: application/json'", "-d", payloadJson, "https://confluence/rest/api/content"}

execErr := syscall.Exec(curlcmd, args, env)
   if execErr != nil {
      panic(execErr)
}
fmt.Println(curlCmd)
```

When the curlCmd from that last line there prints it can be copied and pasted into the terminal and it works however when going through golang it comes with a format not supported.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
payload := `{"type":"page","title":"Testpage","space":{"key":"ITDept"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>Blank Page.</p>","representation":"storage"}}}`
cmd := exec.Command("curl", "-ku", "login:pass", "-X", "POST", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", payload, "http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content")
p, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%s\n", p)
```

Important change from code in the question:

- Run command directly instead of using bash.
- Specify host name in URL.
- Properly quote the string.

BTW, you can also an interpreted string literal:

```
payload := "{\"type\":\"page\",\"title\":\"Testpage\",\"space\":{\"key\":\"ITDept\"},\"body\":{\"storage\":{\"value\":\"<p>Blank Page.</p>\",\"representation\":\"storage\"}}}"
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: Odd so it needs the backticks ` but they do not show up in the curl when I fmt.Println(cmd)  So the curl looks like this.  curl -ku login:pass -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'-d {"type":"page","title":"Testpage","space":{"key":"ITDept"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>Blank Page.</p>","representation":"storage"}}} https://confluence/rest/api/content  and it needs the backticks around payload.  Do you know how I would get those to show up as in the payload you have above has the `` around the outermost {} of the payload var.  Some reason those are stripped off.

Comment: Backticks delimit a [raw string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).  As with all string literals, the delimiters are not part of the string.

Comment: When the command is executed directly, the only quotes required are those required for the string literals.  I used a raw string literal for the JSON because there's no need to add a backslashes in front of the " in the JSON value. Also, I updated answer to remove extra quotes on content type.

Comment: So what you are saying is I need some creative way of including those backticks?  Seems like the API wants those to be passed as well.

Comment: No, you don't need to include the backticks in the string passed to curl. The only string quotes required are those for the string literals in the Go program.  What happens when you run the code as posted in this answer?

Comment: So when I run just a curl for instance in the example on the command line it runs however when I take them away when running it on the command line it goes but the response back tells me it is unsupported format by the API.  So for some reason even from the CLI it requires them.  I get the same error as when I run in it in golang.  For some reason the request needs those ` backticks present.

Comment: BTW Thanks @Cerise Limón for assisting me with this issue as I really sure hope to not have another day go by tomorrow after work and still have this shackling me.